# Executing cy.request before cy.visit seems to cause cy.visit to fail

Tags: cypress

Hello and thanks in advance...

We have what I would consider to be a fairly standard local development environment... frontend running at localhost on one port and the API running at localhost on a different port.

- SPA running locally at http://localhost:4200
- Backend API running locally at http://localhost:65370

We have the need to instruct Cypress to make a PUT request to the API in order to reset some data (long running task) on the backend before the test suite runs. To accomplish this, we are using the "before" hook to call cy.request to our backend API.

The call in the "before" hook using cy.request does in fact make the request to the API running on port 65370 and responds with a 200 status.

When it gets to cy.visit in the beforeEach hook, it hangs up and cy.visit fails (even though the server at http://localhost:4200 is indeed running and functioning as expected).

[image]

However, I can "make it work" if I add cy.visit('/') BEFORE the call to cy.request in the "before" hook. Why is this? And, what is the proper way to address this?

[image]

**cypress.json**

```js
{
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 20000,
    "requestTimeout": 20000,
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4200"
}
```

**mytest.spec.js**

```js
describe('MY TEST COMPONENT', () => {

    before(() => {
       // Un-commenting the line below allows everything to work as expected
       // cy.visit('/')

       cy.request({
         url: 'http://localhost:65370/api/reset',
         method: 'PUT',
         body: <UNIMPORTANT_PAYLOAD>,
         timeout: 200000
       }).then(resestResponse => {
         cy.log('Reset succeeded')
       })
    })
    
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit(`/my-start-url`)
    })

    it('should...', function () {
        expect(true).to.be(true)
    })

})
```

Comment: Could it be cookies-related? `cy.request` will use the cookies set by the initial `cy.visit`.

Comment: @ZachBloomquist ... can you elaborate? I don't see any cookies being set  (after the initial cy.visit() in dev tools)

Comment: You may be able to avoid it by using window.fetch instead of cy.request - looks like Cypress is having trouble establishing the superdomain, see [Same-origin](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Same-origin).

Comment: @Ackroydd  I was attempting to stay within the Cypress ecosystem. But, I'm at a loss at this point. I'll give your suggestion a whirl.

Comment: Unless `cy.visit('/')` has some detrimental effect for your tests, I wouldn't say calling it as an initial step is a bad thing. Cypress wants to establish the domain for subsequent tests and `cy.visit('/')` is the simplest way. Specs that purley test the api would of course need http://localhost:65370 as the domain.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... trying to get this all to work as expected using the "before" hook is proving to be a bit of a hassle. I ended up just removing the "before" hook completely (left the "beforeEach" hook with the cy.visit call) and then just make my cy.request call at the top of my first it()... same diff.